# Dynamically creating campaign using template id using mailsnake in django

Tags: django, mailchimp

I dynamically create campaign from my website using mailsnake in django framework. Want to add the data and images directly into campaign for that i add the html data into the sections like postcard_heading00, postcard_image, std_content00.
Write the code as below:

```
mailsnake = MailSnake('apikey')

template_option = {'list_id':xxxx, 'subject':'testing', 'from_email':'xxxxx', 'from_name':'Test', 'to_name':'', 'template_id':54457, 'inline_css':True, 'generate_text': True, 'title':'testing' }

template_content = {"html_postcard_heading00":"<h1>Testing</h1>","html_std_content00":"<h1>Testing</h1>","html_postcard_image":"<img src='image_path'>"}
```

and pass this content to

```
campaignCreate(type='regular',options = template_option,content=template_content)
```

method.
Campaigns creates properly, but the content still not added into the campaign.

Can please anybody tell me why this happens?

Comment: The data will be added into the sections like "std_preheader_content", "std_preheader_links,"std_social",and "std_footer". Anything will be added into the above section image or text thats added properly. Problem with the sections like "postcard_heading00", "std_content00" and "postcard_image" section. Is there any problem with the repeatable section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is because of Repeatable section. Repeatable section having different way to add data.
Change the template content as below.

```
template_content = {'html_repeat_1:0:postcard_heading00':postcard_heading[0],
                    'html_repeat_1:0:postcard_image': postcard_img,
                    'html_repeat_1:0:std_content00': std_content[0]}
```

I done this way and problem gets solved.